# Finding complex roots of equations to find the splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find the splitting field of $x^3 -2$.

First I don't remember how to find the complex roots. The book glosses over this and says the roots $\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2}(\frac{-1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2}),\sqrt[3]{2}(\frac{-1 - i\sqrt{3}}{2})$.

Then it says we get the splitting field by adjoining these three roots and get the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3})$. What does adjoin mean and how do we get this splitting field?

Comment: So the roots are the cube roots of $2$, and these are found to be the cube roots of $1$ times the real cube root of $2$. Roots of unity are found on the unit circle in the Argand diagram. "Adjoin" simply means to extend the field by adding these elements and all the other elements they generate. But if you are struggling with these concepts you will need to work them out yourself - because to deal with splitting fields in this context you will need to be confident and fluent in the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $x^3 - 2 = 0$, we obtain $x^3 = 2$.  Switching to complex numbers (in preparation to get all three cube roots), letting $k$ range over the integers,
\begin{align*}
x^3 &= 2 \mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i} k}  \\
x &= \sqrt[3]{2} \mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i} k/3}  \end{align*}
If you plot these on the Argand plane, you get three points repeated infinitely many times.  One is at $\sqrt[3]{2}$, one at
$$  \sqrt[3]{2} ( \cos(2\pi/3) + \mathrm{i}\sin(2 \pi/3) ) = \sqrt[3]{2}\left( \frac{-1}{2} + \mathrm{i}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)  \text{,}  $$
and one at
$$  \sqrt[3]{2} ( \cos(4\pi/3) + \mathrm{i}\sin(4 \pi/3) ) = \sqrt[3]{2}\left( \frac{-1}{2} + \mathrm{i}\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)  \text{.}  $$

$\Bbb{Q}$ is a field.  This field does not contain these three roots.  First, $\Bbb{Q}$ does not contain $\sqrt[3]{2}$.  When we adjoin $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to the field $\Bbb{Q}$, we obtain $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, denoting the algebraic field extension with basis given by enough powers of the new element that if we included one more power, we would get an element of $\Bbb{Q}$ --   $\{1, \sqrt[3]{2}, (\sqrt[3]{2})^2\}$.  Here we stop after $(\sqrt[3]{2})^2$ because $(\sqrt[3]{2})^3 = 2 \in \Bbb{Q}$.  Since we are extending by the root of an algebraic equation, we have an algebraic extension.  The general element of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is
$$  a_0 1 + a_1 \sqrt[3]{2} + a_2 (\sqrt[3]{2})^2  \text{,}  $$
with $a_0, a_1, a_2 \in \Bbb{Q}$.  If this looks like a $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space with the basis I mentioned above, it is.

Notice that the general element of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is real, so can't reach either of the two complex roots.  However,
$$  \{1/2, -1/2, \sqrt[3]{2}\} \subseteq \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})  \text{,}  $$
so the only thing we are missing is the subexpression $\mathrm{i}\sqrt{3}$ to be able to write those other two roots using the field operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division).  (Recall that a field is closed under these operations (excepting division by zero), so an expression written using these operations and elements of the field is just some element of the field.)

If we adjoin $\sqrt{-3}$, we obtain $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})(\sqrt{-3}) = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt{-3})$.  The new basis over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is $\{1,\sqrt{-3}\}$.  The resulting basis over $\Bbb{Q}$ is the cartesian product of the two bases: $\{1, \sqrt[3]{2}, (\sqrt[3]{2})^2, \sqrt{-3}, \sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{-3}, (\sqrt[3]{2})^2\sqrt{-3}\}$.  So a general element of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt{-3})$ is a $\Bbb{Q}$-linear combination of those six basis elements.  Notice that with the extensions, we are able to write $\displaystyle \sqrt[3]{2}\left(\frac{-1}{2} + \mathrm{i}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)$ using field operations and elements of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt{-3})$ and likewise for the third root.

So we have a field extension in which all three roots are elements.  That makes this a splitting field -- we are able to split (factor) the original polynomial into monic linear factors expressed using coefficients in this extension.  (In fact, since the factors are  linear, each has only two coefficients, and since each factor is monic, the leading coefficient is $1$, so the only coefficients we use in this factorization are the roots of the polynomial: $\displaystyle (x - \sqrt[3]{2})\left(x - \sqrt[3]{2}\left( \frac{-1}{2} + \mathrm{i}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)\right)\left(x - \sqrt[3]{2}\left( \frac{-1}{2} + \mathrm{i}\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)\right)$.)

Comment: A couple questions, can you confirm what the notation means for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt{-3})$? It means we have our elements are ${a + b\sqrt{-3}|a,b \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})}$? And the new basis is the cartesian product of $\{1, \sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{4}\}$ and $\{1,\sqrt{-3}\}$? Then the roots of $x^3 - 2$ are a linear combination of this basis, therefore $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3})$ is a splitting field

Comment: @UpCup : "... are a $\Bbb{Q}-linear combination ..." -- we have three fields under discussion, so we should be clear about which one is used for coefficients in linear combinations.  Other than that minor edit, I agree with what you have written.